# qtip persistent "tip"

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

im trying to make a tooltip "persistent" for a specific amount of time until or unless the user clicks somewhere else or moves his mouse over another anchor associated with a tooltip..

basically the tooltip that appears will be "scrollable" so the user needs to be able to scroll it...

```
$(this).qtip({  content: {
              text: 'wait.....',
              url: '<?php echo site_url('welcome/get_event_tooltip');?>',
              data: { id: tripID},
              method: 'post'


         },style: { 
      width: 300,
      height:135,
      padding: 5,
      //background: '#A2D959',
      color: 'black',
      overflow:'auto',
      textAlign: 'center',
      border: {
         width: 7,
         radius: 5
       //  color: '#A2D959'
      },
      tip: true,
      solo: true,
    show: { ready: true, delay: 0 },
  hide: {
        fixed: true,
        when: {
            event: 'unfocus'
        }
    },
      name: 'green' // Inherit the rest of the attributes from the preset dark style
   }
            });
```

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?

Comment: My solution didn't work or you didn't try it?

Answer (score 0):

To make the tip scroll with your page you can set the:

```
position: {
    adjust: { 
        scroll: true
    },
```

You already are closing the tip when it loses focus so the only other thing to accomplish would be the timed closing of the tip. My thought to do this would be in the `show` event you can set a timer to trigger the close of the qtip.

```
        events: {

            }, //render
            show: function () {
            //setup timer to close qtip......
```